# bit vs a bit, which one to use when?

Tags: prepositions, articles, adjectives, nouns, indefinite-article

I've got a slight confusion while using them.

I believe "a bit" is used in the case when we are thinking from an "a little" perspective.

ex- he is a bit too late.

When shall we use "bit"?
As per the articles, we should not use indefinite articles for noncountable nouns.
Could anyone provide a little clarity on this?

Comment: _A bit_ (a small quantity, or a small piece) is countable.

Comment: bit became countable after an article was used.

Comment: It takes an article _because_ it is countable. There is no such concept as _bit_ as an uncountable noun.

Answer (score 1):

**A bit** can mean *a tiny thing* or *a small amount*. It can also be used in computing to mean *a single unit that may be on or off* (this meaning is contraction of ***b**inary dig**it*** and is not really relevant to your question).

There isn't a situation I can think of where you would use "bit" without an article. You can use "little" that way, as in: **He has little money left over** (which carries a different connotation than **He has a little money left over**). But you would never say **He has bit money left over.**

Comment: That's what, then why shouldn't I use an indefinite article with "bit"? or shall we assume that it is not mandatory to use an article in every sentence?

Comment: @rahul, I think "bit" will *always* take an article, as Kate said. Whether you use a definite article ("the bit") or indefinite ("a bit") depends on what you mean: **a bit of jelly** or perhaps **the bit of jelly on his tie**.

Answer (score 1):

> ex- he is a bit too late.

Here, "a bit" is used idiomatically and acts as an adverb meaning  slightly/somewhat/to a small degree. Followed by the adverbs "too" and "late", it can modify either of the two, depending on which one you may want to stress:

> He's a bit *too* late/He's a bit too *late*.

By the way, in this meaning "a bit" itself can be modified by, say, "little/ tad":

> He's a little bit too late/He's a tad bit too late.